# Setting Up UNIX cron job from Wordpress

Tags: linux, wordpress

My hosting provides a `cpanel` interface to add a `cron` job. I do not want to manually add a `cron` job via this interface. I want to add and schedule a `cron` job via a script, preferably from a WordPress plugin.

I do not want to use the WordPress native function which is `wp_cron()` either.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

why don't you try [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/) which allows you to control and add cron job to your liking? or [Advanced Cron Manager](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-cron-manager/screenshots/) which gives more than what WP Control offers. Both are WP plugins.